# How to change the default source directory for org-attach?

Tags: org-mode, org-attach

When using org-attach (using the standard `C-c C-a a` command), the default source directory (for the find-file minibuffer) is "~/Org/roam". How do I change that to a different directory, specifically "~/Downloads"?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Are you going to create multiple attachments using files in `~/Downloads`?  If you only have a single file, then deleting `~/Org/roam` in the minibuffer and typing `~/Downloads/...` is probably the quickest and most convenient way. If you have more than one, then I would enable the `dired-dwim` facility and open `~/Downloads` in a second window.

Comment: Because 95% of the time I'm attaching files that I downloaded, and so I want the download folder to be the default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest approach seems to be to temporarily set the function `read-file-name` to look in the target folder. This can be done with the excellent `noflet` [package](https://github.com/nicferrier/emacs-noflet):

```
(defun azr/org-attach ()
  "Org-attach but looks in downloads folder first. Requires noflet."
  (interactive)
  (noflet ((read-file-name (&rest args)
                           (funcall this-fn "Select file: " "~/Downloads")))
    (org-attach)))
```

Or a more complicated answer using the built-in advice capabilities:

```
(defun azr/org-attach-read-file-name-downloads (&rest args)
  '("Select file to attach: " "~/Downloads"))

(defun azr/org-attach ()
  (interactive) 
  (advice-add 'read-file-name :filter-args 'azr/org-attach-read-file-name-downloads)
  (unwind-protect ; make sure to remove advice if user cancels org-attach
      (org-attach)
    (advice-remove 'read-file-name 'azr/org-attach-read-file-name-downloads)))
```